# pandas dataframe columns' product operation exists bug?

Tags: python, pandas

Usually I create a new column df['c'] = df['a'] * df['b'] to calculate a production between column a and column b where df is a pandas's dataframe dtypes are float64. And [pandas officially recommended this method instead of ".mul()" method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-binary-operations). But when I run the code in the following I find bugs.

```
def func(sym):
    location="D:\\data\\"
    df=pd.read_csv(location+sym+".csv")
    df['c']=df['A']*df['B'] # bug existing method (1)
    # df['c']=df['A'].mul(df['B'],axis=0) #replacing method (2)

    .....

for sym in symbollist:
    func(sym)
```

I use code below to clean stocks data, obiviously df may be huge.But len(symbollist) only equals to 50. After codes have been run many times, method(1) may lead to random symbol's column c's value assigning to zero while method (2) perform well from the beginning to the end.

I use eclipse and Anaconda's newest version and python is 2.7. Pandas: 0.17.1, Numpy:1.10.1.

Comment: post raw input data and your numpy and pandas version

Comment: it may just be question of variable type in your columns A and/or B. try to cast them to some numeric format maybe.

Comment: @EdChum I have post my pandas and numpy's version. raw input data is huge, and it is a csv file. If you want , i could email to you and plz tell me your mail address.

Comment: @edouard Yep, I will try to use other numeric format to repace float64

Comment: can't you just copy/past lines which cause a problem from your csv file to SO?

Comment: @edouard    SO is ? I am confused

Comment: @edouard  each symbol's csv file is more than 100MB.... and I am confirmed csv file is OK. because same csv and same code in my home computer being running ok.